# How should I comprehend the NavigationView declaration Code in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The declaration of 'NavigationView' in SwiftUI is so confusing.(Maybe I don't good at the Swift.) In the declaration 'NavigationView' is a struct, but the initializer even has no body, just like a protocol declaration.

The NavigationView declaration like this:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, *)
@available(watchOS, unavailable)
public struct NavigationView<Root> where Root : View {

    public init(root: () -> Root)

    public var body: _View { get }

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    public typealias Body
}
```

[NavigationView declaration code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBuJ1.png)

I copy 'NavigationView' declaration style, code some similar codes, just like below.

My imitation code like this:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, *)
public struct MyNavigationView<Root> where Root:View {
    public init(root: () -> Root)
    public var body: _View { get }
    public typealias Body
}
```

But there are some errors just like:

```
"initializer requires a body"
"Expected '{' to start getter definition"
"Expected '=' in type alias declaration"
```

[my imitation code and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgFRD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the *interface* of a Swift file. Similar to a header file, it shows you all the members of this class/struct/enum/whatever that you can access and their signatures.

So you are not supposed to be able to just copy and paste the code and be able to compile it. It's not actual code. It's just telling you the signatures of each of those members. For example, by looking at the file, you can tell that the initialiser takes a `() -> Root` closure.

I am pretty sure SwiftUI is not open source, so you can't easily get the source code of it.

You can actually see the interfaces of your own code by using the assistant editor. It's just under the "Counterparts" section:

[image]

Comment: OK, I get it. Thank you very much.